# Display new tag to the newly added content

Tags: views

I am trying to show "NEW!" to the recently added.
I know there is something to do with the Views module, but I couldn't find how to get it done.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it easily by adding new field **Node: Has new content** in views, it will show **NEW** status when a new node is added.

Comment: This is correct. As side note, it will add the remark for nodes that have been changed since the last time the user read them too.